# Adding movable Xaml object to MapControl on Windows 10 Mobile

Tags: c#, google-maps, uwp, windows-10-mobile

Hi everyone I'm working on a UWP Google Map Client for windows 10 and I shared it's source code on GitHub
https://github.com/NGame1/UWPGmaps
I created a DraggablePin User control to my project when I add it to my MapControl (`MapControl.Children.Add()`) it works great on Windows.Desktop device family but on mobile when I move the map my control will gone and sometimes it get visible again ! don't know where is the problem.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="GoogleMapsUnofficial.View.OnMapControls.DraggablePin"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:GoogleMapsUnofficial.View.OnMapControls"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Ellipse Height="30" Width="30" Fill="Blue" 
         Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" Margin="-15,-15,0,0"/>
```

this is my XAML for usercontrol and it's the code behind

```
using GoogleMapsUnofficial.View.DirectionsControls;
using GoogleMapsUnofficial.ViewModel.GeocodControls;
using GoogleMapsUnofficial.ViewModel.PlaceControls;
using System;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.Storage.Streams;
using Windows.UI.Popups;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

// The User Control item template is documented at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace GoogleMapsUnofficial.View.OnMapControls
{
    public sealed partial class DraggablePin : UserControl
    {
        #region Private Properties
        private object ClassInitializer;
        private MapControl _map;

    #endregion

    #region Constructor

    public DraggablePin(MapControl map, object Sender)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        _map = map;
        _map.CenterChanged += _map_CenterChanged;
        this.Tapped += DraggablePin_Tapped;
        ClassInitializer = Sender;
    }

    private async void DraggablePin_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async delegate
        {
            if (ClassInitializer.GetType() == typeof(DirectionsMainUserControl))
            {
                var Pointer = (await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/InAppIcons/GMP.png")));
                if (DirectionsMainUserControl.Origin == null)
                {
                    DirectionsMainUserControl.Origin = _map.Center;
                    _map.MapElements.Add(new MapIcon()
                    {
                        Location = _map.Center,
                        NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0),
                        Title = "Origin",
                        Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(Pointer),
                    });
                    DirectionsMainUserControl.OriginAddress = await GeocodeHelper.GetAddress(_map.Center);
                }
                else if (DirectionsMainUserControl.Destination == null)
                {
                    DirectionsMainUserControl.Destination = _map.Center;
                    _map.MapElements.Add(new MapIcon()
                    {
                        Location = _map.Center,
                        NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0),
                        Title = "Destination",
                        Image = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromFile(Pointer)
                    });
                    DirectionsMainUserControl.DestinationAddress = await GeocodeHelper.GetAddress(_map.Center);
                }
            }
            if (ClassInitializer.GetType() == typeof(SavedPlacesUserControl))
            {
                if (SavedPlacesUserControl.PName == string.Empty)
                {
                    await new MessageDialog("Specify a name for this place").ShowAsync();
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        SavedPlacesVM.AddNewPlace(new SavedPlacesVM.SavedPlaceClass()
                        {
                            Latitude = _map.Center.Position.Latitude,
                            Longitude = _map.Center.Position.Longitude,
                            PlaceName = SavedPlacesUserControl.PName
                        });
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        await new MessageDialog(ex.Message).ShowAsync();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    ~DraggablePin()
    {
        ClassInitializer = null;
        _map.CenterChanged -= _map_CenterChanged;
        _map = null;
    }
    #endregion

    #region Public Properties

    /// <summary>
    /// A boolean indicating whether the pushpin can be dragged.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Draggable { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region  Public Events

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the pushpin is being dragged.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<Geopoint> Drag;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the pushpin starts being dragged.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<Geopoint> DragStart;

    /// <summary>
    /// Occurs when the pushpin stops being dragged.
    /// </summary>
    public Action<Geopoint> DragEnd;

    #endregion

    #region Private Methods

    private void _map_CenterChanged(MapControl sender, object args)
    {
        //Reset the map center to the stored center value.
        //This prevents the map from panning when we drag across it.
        MapControl.SetLocation(this, sender.Center);

    }
    #endregion
}
}
```

if you want to try it on the source code after building project and installing on Windows 10 Mobile click on Menu and directions a blue dot will appear on your screen 
Thanks

Comment: which win10 (mobile) version? MS stopped providing the same build level to desktop/phone, so there could be API that are on desktop but not available on mobile.

Comment: @magicandre1981 I'm using SDK 14393 it's available on pone too and my phone is a 950XL build 15254 (witch means Creators Update SDK)

Comment: Do you have any other mobile devices to test the issue and it always happens? Is it a specific device? Could you try to restart the mobile to test it again?

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT I tried On Lumia 950XL dual sim RM-1116. Also some other windows phone users mentioned such error on Lumia 820, 640XL and etc.

Comment: @BreezeLiu-MSFT No idea ?